# get error when try fstrim

Tags: 13.10, ssd, trim

Below is my /etc/cron.daily/fstrim file:

```
#! /bin/sh  

# By default we assume only / is on an SSD. 
# You can add more SSD mount points, separated by spaces.
# Make sure all mount points are within the quotes. For example:
# SSD_MOUNT_POINTS='/ /boot /home /media/my_other_ssd'  

SSD_MOUNT_POINTS='/ /home /media/data'  

for mount_point in $SSD_MOUNT_POINTS
do  
    fstrim $mount_point  
done
```

and when I try: `sudo /etc/cron.daily/fstrim` I got this error:
 
`fstrim: /media/data: FITRIM ioctl failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device`

the file system of `/media/data` is ntfs-3g , I mount it in `/etc/fstab`, this is how I mount it:
`UUID=883E7F6B3E7F5164 /media/data ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.UTF-8,noatime,nodiratime     0       0`
Why I get this error? How can I fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

NTFS file systems cannot be trimmed in Linux, it is not supported. From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trim_%28computing%29) :

> Not all filesystems make use of Trim. Among the filesystems that can issue Trim requests automatically are Ext4,[25] Btrfs,[26] FAT, GFS2[27] and XFS.[28] However, this is disabled by default due to performance concerns,[29] but can be enabled by setting the "discard" mount option. Ext3, NILFS2 and OCFS2 offer ioctls to perform offline trimming.